# There is no mature yaml library for erlang

Tags: erlang, yaml

Is there a mature and stable YAML library for Erlang that someone has actually used? I can't seem to find one anywhere

Update:
I have searched and searched and still not found one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yamler](https://github.com/superbobry/yamler) seems like a good library.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [incomplete implementation of YAML parsing](http://github.com/tim/erlang-beanstalk/blob/master/src/beanstalk_yaml.erl) in [Erlang beanstalk client library](http://github.com/tim/erlang-beanstalk/).

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be able to parse basic YAML which is good.

Comment: I'll keep searching for one which can also edit the parsed tree and generate YAML from it.

Comment: Your right, I should implement one, but I'll admit I am not really a very good developer and I dont have the first clue as to how to go about implementing this

Comment: It's the middle of 2011 and still no serious yaml implementation for Erlang.

My work-around was to use python and pyyaml to load the yaml file, print it as an erlang term and then have erlang parse that.

An idea for a real erlang yaml parser would be to wrap libyaml with NIFs.  This would only provide an event stream; another layer would need to be written on top of that (probably in pure erlang) to form a nice structured erlang term.

Answer (score 2):

Check https://github.com/yakaz/yamerl

- It's pure erlang - no NIFs or external dependencies
- It's updated reqularly as needed (look at the commit history)
- Testcases
- Supports YAML 1.2

Comment: have you ever tried this? I tried and found it can't work. I run this `yamerl_constr:string("Hello World!").` and it shows some erorrs,I use R15  version.

Comment: @sherlock: You need to start the `yamerl` application first: `application:start(yamerl), yamerl_constr:string("Hello World!"). % Returns
["Hello World!"]`